# Like Function - Retrieve And Pass Value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a like function but I have a problem with assigning like id to the comment id.

Code:

INDEX.PHP

```
include "includes/db.php";
include "comment.class.php";

    .....
    .....

    $comment = array();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM box");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $comment[] = new Comment($rows);

    }

    foreach ($comment as $c) {

        echo $c->createComment();

    }

            <div id="addCommentArea">
                <p>Add a Comment</p>
                <form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
                    <div>
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

                        <label for="body">Comment Body</label>
                        <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>

                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

COMMENT.PHP

```
.....
.....

class Comment

{

    private $data = array();

public function __construct($row)
{
    //  The constructor
    $this->data = $row;                   
    }

    public function createComment()

    {

    $d = &$this->data;

            $link_open = '';
        $link_close = '';        

    return "<div class='comment'>
                <div class='username'>".$link_open.$d['name'].$link_close."</div>
                <p>".$d["body"]."</p>
              <a href='' id='$comment_id' class='like_button'><img src='thumbs_up.png'/></a>&nbsp;<span class='like_show$comment_id'
style='font-weight:bold;font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;fontsize:12px;position:relative;top:-2px;'>$like_count</span>
            </div>";

    }

    }
```

So i'm trying to pass the comment_id and like_count here:

```
<a href='' id='$comment_id' class='like_button'><img src='thumbs_up.png'/></a>&nbsp;<span class='like_show$comment_id' style='font-weight:bold;font-family:Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif;fontsize:12px;position:relative;top:-2px;'>$like_count</span>
```

I tried to add a while loop, go through the table and get the comment_id. But I can't put the return inside the while loop cause then I'll get only one result (so the like button for each comment will get the same id and if i like one comment, all the other comments will be liked). If I just create a while loop and put the results in an array, then I also cannot pass them in the comment_id to print the like button for each comment.

I also tried to create a separate function for the like button, get the comment_id from the first function (createComment) and pass it to the second function (let's say ''likeComment''). It didn't work as well but I'm not sure if I did it right. How can i pass values from one function to another? Is there any other way to get the value I want?

Any ideas? The solution is probably simple, but I'm really struggling with it. Everything works fine and I'm so close to make the commentbox works.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the issue. You create the comments using the data from the row. So what data don't you have access to? The comment_id should already be there. Posting *all* of your code may shed some light on what you are having problems with.

Comment: The comment_id is the data that I don't have access to. It said that ''comment_id seems to be uninitialized''. I will edit the first post in order to post all of the code.

Comment: @Supericy i've just added all the code. (i have one javascript and one more php file but these files are working fine, what i want to do is to find a way to retrieve each comment_id in order to assign a like id to it.

Comment: Is comment_id a column in your table? If so, then you should access using `$d['comment_id']`. Or if you prefer, you could set `$comment_id = $d['comment_id']` above your return statement, and then your current code should work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to share data between the object's methods, you should assign/access the variables from within each function as $this->variable name. I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for...

```
class myClass {
    public $test_var;

    function one () {
        $this->test_var = 'a string'; // sets the value
    }

    function two() {
        echo $this->test_var; // prints 'a string'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. I'm not sure if i can do this for an array but I'll give it a try.